# Can't make 'checked' working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, radio-button

I know that it has been asked 100s of imes, but I can't find a solution fitting in my case.

I have these radio buttons:

```
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" data-bind="checked:loadFilteredHistory">1
</div>
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="2" data-bind="checked:loadFilteredHistory">2
</div>
```

as you can see I'm trying to call a function named `loadFilteredHistory`

and it is as simple as:

```
loadFilteredHistory = function(){
   console.log("I'm inside of teh function");
};
```

But when I click on the radiobutton nothing happens. What am I missing here? Why I can't call the function? I know that it is something extremely small, but I'm not able to spot ot it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a observable to bind to the checkbox:

```
self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
```

Then subscribe to that observable to perform your actions when the selected option changes:

```
self.selectedOption.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log('selectedOption change', newValue);
});
```

You can now just bind `selectedOption` to the `checked` bindinghandler:

```
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" data-bind="checked:selectedOption" />1
</div>
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="2" data-bind="checked:selectedOption" />2
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjroesink/bt3mU/ for a demo

Comment: I would follow this suggestion. The click-approach is closer to the jQuery-way of handling events. This is in my opinion a better design when working with viewmodels.

Answer (score 2):

The checked databinding is more for synchronizing (two-way-binding) the current checkbox value with a variable in your model, if you want to listen for selects you can bind the click instead like this:

```
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" data-bind="click:loadFilteredHistory">1
</div>
<div class="left-floated-box" >
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="2" data-bind="click:loadFilteredHistory">2
</div>
```

Then you need to create a model with the corresponding function, and finally you apply these bindings with ko.applyBindings passing in your model. I added a console.log-statement to show you how you can get a hold of the clicked checkbox through event.currentTarget.

```
var viewModel = {
    loadFilteredHistory: function(model, event) { 
        console.log("Inside the function");
        console.log("Clicked checkbox = " + event.currentTarget.value);
        return true;
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I tried to bind teh click, but when I click on it the circle is not getting teh selection dot in it. The function runs, but the radio button is not marked as selected :(

Comment: My bad, the function should return true, try my new version.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$('.left-floated-box input').click(function() {
   if($('input').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gdyk/)

Comment: Great, but I will put some data to this function later.

Answer (score 0):

You missed " /input " code

```
<div class="left-floated-box">
    <input type="radio" id="button" name="options" value="1">1 </input>
</div>

<div class="left-floated-box">
    <input type="radio" id="button" name="options" value="2">2 </input>
</div>


$('#button').click(function() {
  alert("I'm inside of teh function");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `loadFilteredHistory` a method of your viewModel? By the looks of your snippet it's not.

Try something like this:

`var myViewModel = {
  radioButtonValue: ko.observable()
}
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);`

You may also want to clarify that this is knockout.js question. =)

UPDATE:

Actually from the looks of it, this binding does not allow function to be passed a value.
It'expects an observable value. For radiobuttons it will pass new value to your observable.
I've updated snippet above.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

To call a function when this change occurs you may use `myViewModel.radioButtonValue.subscribe(loadFilteredHistory)`